# AccessVBA- refer to a Subform and change its properties in a module

Tags: ms-access, vba

Using A2007 and A2003.  I have several main forms with subforms.  When certain conditions are met I need to make several changes that include changing AllowEdits property for one of the subforms.  I want to do this in a module.

On the Main form I have:
Call ModuleName("SubformName")

In the Module:
Public Sub ModuleName(FN)
With Screen.activeform
  .FN.Form.AllowEdits = False

I get error 2465.  If I put the actual name of the subform where I have FN, works.  What am I missing?  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With `Screen.ActiveForm.FN.Form.AllowEdits = False`, Access is looking for a control literally named `FN`. You need to change the syntax so that your variable FN gets resolved. Try `Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(FN).Form.AllowEdits = False`, which can be shortened to `Screen.ActiveForm(FN).Form.AllowEdits = False` because Controls is the default property of a form.